# Go to file by link

Tags: php, file

I store data in text file.

And when user enter in address bar something like

- `my_syte.com/aaa` - (without extension)- I need to file_get_contents aaa.txt file
- `my_syte.com/bbb` - I need to file_get_contents bbb.txt file

Please advise the most powerful way of do it. Apache server.
Thanks

Comment: Get the values from the url, find a way to open a file in php(google) and then add the variable you get from the url to the file open function with `'.txt'` behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `Apache` servers you can use `mod-rewrite` in `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ /$1.txt [L]
```

if your files can contain `-` or `_` or numbers then use:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /$1.txt [L]
```

<strike>On `nginx` servers it's more complicated but some of them works with `.htaccess`. On other servers there may be entirely different approach. It's hard to help you without more informations.</strike>

As you said it's Apache, then use examples above. Either edit or create `.htaccess` file on your webroot (directory which is accessed by domain). First check if it were there (could be hidden) and if it exists then only edit it (add lines at the top).

If it doesn't exist, then create one by yourself.

Comment: ok. but if I have index.html with textarea. I when I go by this link my_site.com/aaa I need fill this textarea from text file. I use php to file_get_contents. It doesn't work RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ script.php?key=$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please give us some insights about your server? Apache nginx?

In Apache, you can achieve that with url rewriting.

Enable mod_rewrite in apache
Put the following line of code in .htaccess on the same location of my_site.com/

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    ^/foo$  /foo.txt [PT]
```

to make it generic

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    ^/*$  /foo.txt [PT]
```

Maybe I am wrong in sytax based on your specific server configuration. You need to make the best possible regular expression for this case.